# How to use current layer name in FME PythonCaller?

Tags: python, fme-form, data-interoperability, fmeobjects

In a PythonCaller (FME 2014 SP4 in Data Interop in ArcGIS 10.3), I'd like to do some conditional processing based on the layer that I'm currently processing. I'm feeding in a text file of layers dynamically at runtime, so the layer(s) being processed can vary. I'd like to do something like the psuedocode below:

```
import fmeobjects
def processFeature(feature):
    # Get which layer is currently being processed
    layer_name = somehow get current layername via fmeobjects??
    # do some logical processing of fields based on what layer we are processing
    pass
```

Not sure if there is something in `FME_MacroValues` that exposes this (looked and couldn't find much) or if I need to expose it somehow from my source and then pipe it into my PythonCaller perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add an AttributeExposer, expose the `fme_feature_type` attribute
2. Connect the AttributeExposer to a AttributeCreator to push `fme_feature_type` out an attribute (named `fme_feature_type` below)
3. In the PythonCaller, get your attribute by: `layer_name = feature.getAttribute("fme_feature_type")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume your text file is like a CSV with a header called "LayerName" and each row is a different layer.  In that case, your function would be something like this:

```
import fmeobjects
def processFeature(feature):
    # Get which layer is currently being processed
    layer_name = feature.getAttribute("LayerName")
    # do some logical processing of fields based on what layer we are processing
    pass
```

Comment: Didn't actually try this, but totally seems like a viable solution that should work. Thanks.